# Open/closed function

Tags: php, functions, shortcode

I've created an open/closed function for a website that I'm working on and I'm trying to add the final touch but I've got stuck.

How can I add a span show it shows a green dot with a css pulse animation for open and a red one with a pulse affect with closed. I've added an example.
https://www.clicky.co.uk/

**Shortcode:**

```
[linestatus] [linestatus open_time="08:00:00" closed_time="17:00:00" open_text="open" closed_text="closed"]
```

**PHP Function**

```
add_shortcode( 'linestatus', 'line_status_handler' );
function line_status_handler( $atts ) { 
    extract( shortcode_atts( array( 
        'open_time' => '09:00:00', 
        'closed_time' => '17:00:00', 
        'open_text' => 'our lines are open', 
        'closed_text' => 'our lines are closed', 
    ), $atts ) ); 

    if ( time() >= strtotime( $open_time ) && time() <= strtotime( $closed_time ) ) { 
        $output = $open_text; 
    } else { 
        $output = $closed_text; 
    } 
    return $output; 
}
```

Comment: The easiest solution is to use a css psuedo to do your animation. Secondly, you should try to create the code then ask on stackoverflow as this is a css issue not a wordpress issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've sourced the CSS from

https://codepen.io/vram1980/pen/Kyaie

all credit above. Putting it with your function, you can do something like this:

```
add_shortcode( 'linestatus', 'line_status_handler' );
function line_status_handler( $atts ) { 
    extract( shortcode_atts( array( 
        'open_time' => '09:00:00', 
        'closed_time' => '17:00:00', 
        'open_text' => 'our lines are open', 
        'closed_text' => 'our lines are closed', 
    ), $atts ) ); 

    $opened = (time() >= strtotime( $open_time )) ? true : false;
    $notClosed = (time() <= strtotime( $closed_time )) ? true : false;;

    $status = ($opened &&  $notClosed) ? 'open' : 'closed';

    add_action('wp_footer',function(){
        ?>
        <style>
        .ring-container {
            position: relative;
            height: 50px;
        }

        .circle {
            width: 15px;
            height: 15px;
            background-color: #62bd19;
            border-radius: 50%;
            position: absolute;
            top: 23px;
            left: 23px;
        }
        .ringring {
            border: 3px solid #62bd19;
            -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
            height: 25px;
            width: 25px;
            position: absolute;
            left: 15px;
            top: 15px;
            -webkit-animation: pulsate 1s ease-out;
            -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite; 
            opacity: 0.0
        }

        .ring-container--closed .circle {
            background-color: red;
        }
        .ring-container--closed .ringring {
            border: 3px solid #ff7777;
        }

        @-webkit-keyframes pulsate {
            0% {-webkit-transform: scale(0.1, 0.1); opacity: 0.0;}
            50% {opacity: 1.0;}
            100% {-webkit-transform: scale(1.2, 1.2); opacity: 0.0;}
        }
        </style>
        <?php
    });

    return '
    <div class="ring-container ring-container--'.$status.'">
        <div class="ringring"></div>
        <div class="circle"></div>
    </div>'; 

}
```

You'll probably want to throw that CSS in a stylesheet of your theme. I've wrapped it in an anonymous function with the footer hook so it lands at the bottom of the screen instead of wherever the shortcode is.

Comment: Thanks David. I was more looking at how to get the classes to apply to the open and closed times?

Comment: @JordanKellett I've updated my post

Comment: For some reason the function.php doesn't allow me to save the php function in there. It's returning the following: //i.imgur.com/7tviuJh.png

Comment: in that screen shot, you have started the `return` with a double quote. In your and my code, we both did `return` then single quote.

Comment: I tried with a singular also but the same message appeared. It doesn't have to be in the footer if that would make any difference?

Comment: I was able to copy/paste my snippet into `functions.php` error free via the admin Editor. Try refreshing this screen maybe? I've updated that post like 1000 times.